# Retrieve only a portion of a matched string using regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string like

```
foo (123) bar
```

I want to retrieve all numbers surrounded with the delimiters `(` and `)`.

If I use `varname.match(/\([0-9]+\)/)`, my delimiters are included in the response, and I get "(123)" when what I really want is "123".

How can I retrieve only a portion of the matched string without following it up with `varname.replace()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use capturing (non-escaped) parens:

```
varname.match(/\(([0-9]+)\)/)[1]
```

Comment: The '[1]' is the part the picks the first substring match.  If it was '[0]' instead, it would return the entire match (e.g. '(123)')